# set 'form-data' to jersey client post request

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am writing a rest client which consumes a POST restful sevice of server. 
Now the service expects 2 parameters as part of request in 'form-data'.

If you have across postman rest client, there we have an option to set the form-data, and give key-value pair parameters.

How can we send similar data in Javax rs rest client. Here is the code which I have.

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
...

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
Builder basicRequest = target.request();        
Response response=basicRequest.post();
```

Now how to send 2 parameters namely 'fileName', 'fileVersion' with their values as part of form-data?

Answer (score 14):

After searching all over the internet, here is what worked for me

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
Builder basicRequest = target.request();  
      
Form form = new Form();
form.param("filename", "file.csv");
form.param("version", "1.0");
Response response=basicRequest.post(Entity.form(form), Response.class);
```

Comment: I had to do the exact same thing. Thanks for posting your solution, it worked instantly and I didn't have to do more searching.

Comment: How did you add the content of file.csv?

Comment: There are libraries which we can make use of to create CSV files like apache commons